# how to change date format in node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, ejs

I'm getting date in `node.js` in this format `06.02.2020` but I want to convert it to this format: `06.FEB.2020`
how can I do that?.

ejs code:

```
  <%= convertDate(m.date) %>
```

controller code:

```
  function convertDate(d) {
    const date = new Date(d);
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    let month = date.getMonth();
    month = parseInt(month) < 10 ? `0${month}` : month;

    let day = date.getDate();
    day = parseInt(day) < 10 ? `0${day}` : day;
    return day + "." + month + "." + year;
  }

  var renderListOfMeetings = async function (req, res) {
    try {
      checkRoles(req);
      let meetings = await Meeting.find({});
      //meetings slider
      meetings = setMeetingSliders(meetings);

      res.render('meeting', {
          title: 'Meetings',
          pdfUrl : config.pdfUrl,
          isAdmin : req.roleAdmin,
          sectionBCommittee: [],
          meetings: meetings,
          // your convert date function
          convertDate: convertDate
      });
    }catch(ex) {
      console.log(ex.message);
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a library for conversion, just install that using,

```
npm install dateformat
```

Then write your requirement:

```
var dateFormat = require('dateformat');
```

Then bind the value, in your function:

```
function convertDate(d) {
    var converted_date = dateFormat(d, "dd.mmm.yyyy")
    return converted_date;
}
```

Note: `mmm` in converter format will result into Jan, Feb, Mar etc.
if you want FEB all character in capital then apply `toUpperCase()` on converted date. i.e.

```
function convertDate(d) {
    var converted_date = dateFormat(d, "dd.mmm.yyyy")
    return converted_date.toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function convertMonth(str) {
  const monthNames = ["JAN", "FEB"];
  return str.replace(str.split('.')[1], monthNames[parseInt(str.split('.')[1]) - 1]);
}
```

I've with just tested `06.02.2020`

Answer (score -2):

I usually use **dateformat** npm package for that. Its so simple and awesome.

```
npm i dateformat
```

You can modify the date & time format as per your wish.

```
const dateFormat = require('dateformat');
console.log(dateFormat(new Date(), "ddd mmm dd yyyy HH:MM:ss UTC" ));
```

Refer More Examples [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dateformat)